# Change background with sliding transition depending on button hovered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to redesign my website recently, and I thought the idea to change the main header to change into different backgrounds depending on the button you hover would be cool

However, I know nothing about javascript besides from the absolute basic, so some help would be nice

Here's what I'm trying to to achieve

[image]

Here's the current HTML for the header

```js
let headerContent = `
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="blog/blogmain.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="art/artmain.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="fanart/fanartmain.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="partners/partnersmain.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="guestbook/guestbook.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="https://junessaidotnet.proboards.com/">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="downloads/downloadsmain.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="extras/extrasmain.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="donate/donatemain.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>

  <a href="about/about.html">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" class="button"></a>
`;

document.querySelector('#buttoncontainer').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headerContent);
```

```css
.logocontainer {
        text-align: center;
 }

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0.30%;
  align: center;
 }

.buttoncontainer {
  text-align: center;
 }

.button {
  display: inline-block;
 }

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
  filter: brightness(125%);
 }

.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  filter: brightness(155%);
 }
```

```html
  <div class="logocontainer">
     <a href="index.html">
     <img src="images/badasslogo.png" class="logo"></a>
     </div>

    <div id="buttoncontainer" class="buttoncontainer">
  </div>
```

And the .js file which I use for the buttons, since if I didn't use it, I would have to update every single page manually if I ever wanted to add more buttons to it

Also, if possible
Is there any way to insert the logo into .js file aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated with logo:**

Please take a look at the JavaScript comments. I included a simple transition.

The approach is to `position:absolute;` the banner images. Then, on button hover, create a new image element and insert it behind current image. After a successful promise, remove previous image and trigger CSS animation:

```js
// Here you set the img src of banners. Be sure to have as many as the menu buttons
const banners = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1451187580459-43490279c0fa?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1172&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488590528505-98d2b5aba04b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1451187580459-43490279c0fa?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1172&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550745165-9bc0b252726f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550751827-4bd374c3f58b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597733336794-12d05021d510?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550751827-4bd374c3f58b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488590528505-98d2b5aba04b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550745165-9bc0b252726f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597733336794-12d05021d510?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488590528505-98d2b5aba04b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1451187580459-43490279c0fa?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1172&q=80',
];

let headerContent = `
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="blog/blogmain.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="art/artmain.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="fanart/fanartmain.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="partners/partnersmain.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="guestbook/guestbook.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="https://junessaidotnet.proboards.com/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="downloads/downloadsmain.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="extras/extrasmain.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="donate/donatemain.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
  <a href="about/about.html">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="button"></a>
`;
document.querySelector('#buttoncontainer').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headerContent);

// Grab menu buttons and overlay span
const menuButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#buttoncontainer a');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.bannerContainer .overlay');
const bannerContainer = document.querySelector('.bannerContainer');

// For each menu button, attach an EventListener
menuButtons.forEach((btn, i) => {
  btn.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    // Remove animate class from overlay making it go back to left position
    overlay.classList.remove('animate');

    // Get current Image
    const currentImage = document.querySelector('.bannerContainer img');
    // Load Image function
    loadImage(currentImage, i)

  });
});

// Async Function to load new image
const loadImage = async(currentImage, i) => {
  // Create a new img element, set the img src from array, and the class of 'banner'
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = await banners[i];
  img.classList.add('banner');

  // Wait for it to load
  await new Promise((res) => {
    img.onload = res;
  });

  // Insert new Image before current Image
  bannerContainer.append(img, currentImage);

  // Add Swipe transition and remove current image after half of transition's duration
  overlay.classList.add('animate');
  setTimeout(() => currentImage.remove(), 500);
}
```

```css
.logocontainer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.logocontainer a {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.logocontainer a img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.bannerContainer {
  max-width: 550px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  margin-bottom: 0.30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: auto;
}

.buttoncontainer {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
  filter: brightness(125%);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: -110%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 110%;
  background: #151515;
  z-index: 2;
}

.animate {
  animation: 1s swipe forwards linear;
}

@keyframes swipe {
  0% {
    left: -110%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logocontainer">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class='logo' /></a>
  <div class="bannerContainer">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488590528505-98d2b5aba04b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="initial Banner" class="banner" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="buttoncontainer" class="buttoncontainer">
</div>
```

Comment: You should find a better preload logic. Makes no sense to slide something as a revealer to then asynchronously make a request for the new image - and as result get a *flash of content*.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes true, this is why I suggested to load all `<img>` initially positioned absolute, and depending on the button hover change the `z-index` of each `<img>`. This way you won't have the asynchronous aspect to mess things up.

Comment: This actually works very well, but the only problem is that apparently the logo is gone the moment you hover over something.

Comment: @JuneS.Sai I think I understand what you want. You just need to `position:absolute;` the logo. I am updating the code.

Comment: Hey, your code works perfectly, it was exactly what I was looking for, and I can't thank you enough for that, but I gotta ask, is there any way to make so whenever you're not hovering over any button anymore, it goes back to the default background/the background of the current page?

Answer (score 0):

A JS solution would probably involve having event listeners for mouseenter and mouseleave and toggling a class on some element based on that, but since you said you're not that great at JS, here is a CSS-only approach you can take instead.

```css
.logocontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

:has(button:first-child:hover) .logocontainer {
  background-color: red;
}

:has(button:nth-child(2):hover) .logocontainer {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="logocontainer"></div>

<div id="buttoncontainer" class="buttoncontainer">
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
</div>
```